# Can I change the outcome of a dream?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In a dream, I don't really have a clue what's going on, and they all seem to end the same way with

> the boy bursting into flames

Is there anything else that can happen, or any way I can influence what goes on in a dream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. You can't even run away, Shepard will turn around and run back.

You will *eventually* have to do what you're meant to do, so you might as well get it over with straight away.

Comment: So it's effectively a cut-scene?

Comment: @fredley Pretty much. They just try to make it interesting by having you do all the manual labor, which I might point out makes it less interesting in my eyes.

Comment: It feels a lot like filler to me, which is annoying.

Comment: in my opinion the dreams really didnt add all that much to the game. just 10 minutes of trying to catch up with a boy while you are walking extremely slow.

Comment: @fredley Theoretically it could mean something in the future, but I don't want to spoil anything (as of right now it means pretty much nothing, so it is filler).

Comment: @MrSmooth I know what you are talking about but even then i don't find that the dreams have much significance.

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp The only way it will become more significant is it will mean that he's been *that way* since at least the beginning of the game.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change anything.
These dreams are just some kind of interractive cinematics.

If you go outside the perimeter,  your Shepard will turn back.